# is it possible to use an unsupported resolution/zoom out/something on a win7 netbook? (sw/hw)

Tags: windows-7, resolution, netbook

I have a netbook with windows 7 and a max. resolution of 1024x600. This resolution is usually insufficent to display correctly my programs.
Do you know of any type of software to zoom out the screen, use unsupported resolutions, or to create 'virtual' graphics dysplay so i can get a zoom out effect on mi monitor? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a "scrollable desktop" or a "virtual desktop" program for example [SDesk](http://download.cnet.com/SDesk/3000-2346_4-10078754.html), [GiMeSpace](http://sites.google.com/site/gimespace/) or [Virtual Dimension](http://virt-dimension.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

See [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en) (Free of charge for private use) :

> Dexpot turns your monitor into up
>   to 20. Dexpot creates additional
>   workspaces you can quickly switch
>   between. Take, for example, Desktop 1
>   to listen to your favourite music,
>   surf the web on Desktop 2, use Desktop
>   3 to handle your daily word processing
>   or switch to Desktop 4 for a game of
>   Solitaire.